# WebLogic 10.x - Run Admin server in the background

Tags: weblogic

Like the Title says, I need to run the admin server as a windows service.
Actually, I would be happy evem if there is a command to run the admin server that terminates once the server is up and running.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You normally would set that up during the install process.
But here is the [document](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11035_01/wls100/server_start/winservice.html) that outlines the process.

If you are going to be running instances other than the admin server (managed nodes), then you will also need to set up Node Manager as a service.

Hope that helps
 Bill

Comment: Thanks Bill. However, the document is for the managed servers and not the admin servers.

Comment: It applies to both admin servers and managed servers